# 2 Elements with 1 Event

Tags: jquery

I have 2 places a user can click and both need to fire off the same .click() event

I know I can do 2 click events that I bind to the same function

```
  $('element').click(function(event) {
    bind newfunction();
  });
```

eg: above times 2.

But I wanted to ask if there was a way to have the two events connected to the one click
eg: this is my pseudo code idea

```
 $('element') || $('element').click(function(event) {
   bind newfunction();
 });
```

is a variation of this possible? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just comma separate elements

```
$('elementx, elementy').click(function(event) {
  bind newfunction();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the same class to both elements and use that as your `click` selector.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<a href="mylink_a" class="clicker">a</a>
<a href="mylink_b" class="clicker">b</b>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.clicker').click(function(e){
    // both elements will cause this to fire
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just pull out the handler function and then bind it to both elements:

```
var handler = function(event) {
    // Do stuff...
};

$('#element1').click(handler);
$('#element2').click(handler);
```

Comment: This is the long way to do it (though it would work).  Either mrtsherman or Demian's methods are cleaner in my opinion.